# TikZ arrows not working in Spanish

Tags: tikz-arrows, babel, spanish

In a Spanish translation of a document, the TikZ arrows don't work. The error message I receive is:
`! Argument of \language@active@arg> has an extra }`.

The use of
`\usetikzlibrary{babel}`
does *not* work if the TikZ diagrams are externalized:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\tikzset{>=stealth}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz/]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[<->] (0,-1) -- node[fill=white] {$1/2$} +(4.5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried loading the TikZ library [`babel`](https://tikz.dev/library-babel)? (`\usetikzlibrary{babel}`)

Comment: Don't use the `external` library with the `standalone` class (and certainly not the `tikz` option). That's trying to kill one bird with two stones.